# Space for bootloader and swap space

Tags: dual-boot

I am now attempting to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 alongside Windows 10. I am unsure of how much space should be set aside for the bootloader partition and swap space partition. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Ubuntu now uses a swap file, so no swap partition required. And default install is only / (root) or if UEFI system also an ESP - efi system partition, but it will share Windows ESP if it is UEFI. Most desktops also do not need /boot partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: My desktop is a refurbished Dell Optiplex  3010 DT i5 and might be a little older so I'm not sure I thought it might need a boot partition. By "default install is only root"  what exactly do you mean? to oldfred

Comment: Ubuntu has several default install options. Some totally erase a drive, so do not use those. But standard default install only creates / (root). Swap is not created now as it uses a swap file. And if old BIOS that is all you will have on drive, one large ext4 partition used as / (root). Please review disk space link posted above.

Comment: What do you mean by / (root)? and don't I need a boot partition to choose which operating system when I boot up?  And I am hesitant to use ubuntus default install because it has erased the windows recovery partition on my laptop because it says the partitions cannot be recognized by ubuntu.

Comment: With Ubuntu there is now only one required partition /.  And if you do not turn off Windows fast startup/hibernation. With hibernation flag set, the installer does not see all the NTFS partitions. Some make sure installer sees Windows NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions But if you partition in advance, gparted will show NTFS partition, but may flag as hibernated. Then you can create the ext4 partition for / and optionally /home. Then with Something Else you will see your ext4 partition(s) and can choose which is / and if another /home.

Comment: I have completed the install however when I restarted windows booted and I never got the boot screen to choose from Ubuntu or Windows. Should I assume that I need a sepirate partition for bootloader. I have set the mount point for /.  If I need a sepirate partition for bootloader how do i make another partition? Windows won't allow me to make more than 4. And Windows currently has 2 recovery partitions. I Imagine one for 7 and one for 10. I could possibly erase 7 but it is not big enough for bootloader. Im told it should be about 200MB. It is 100MB. How do I make another partition? To oldfred

Comment: If BIOS, both Windows have boot files in one primary NTFS partition with boot flag. If UEFI you have only one /EFI/Microsoft folder. Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
 IF UEFI have you checked in UEFI boot menu (same as you use to to select installer) and boot ubuntu entry?

Comment: My Dell boots in legacy. What is a boot summery report? And there are 2 recovery partitions for windows not one. Not 2 windows OS only 10 not 7. Im not sure why 2 maybe one for 7 since it was originally installed with 7 and rebuilt for 10. To oldfred

Comment: Please see link above on Boot-Repair and follow its instructions to add Boot-Repair and run the Summary report. If originally Windows 7 probably BIOS/MBR configuration with MBR 4 primary partition limit. Best to have Ubuntu inside an extended partition as a logical partition. Make sure you also have a Windows repair flash drive or install media with recovery console. Windows 10 will keep turning on fast start up (sets hibernation flag) with updates and then you may have to repair it as grub will not boot hibernated Windows.

Comment: I took a chance on just running the boot repair and it worked. I figured if it caused problems with windows i would just reinstall windows 10, but I there have been no problems so i did not have to. Thank you very much for your advice oldfred!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my partitions look like

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ df -m | grep -E 'sda|Used'
Filesystem          1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              140435  16124    117156  13% /
/dev/sda7              316201 122259    177859  41% /home
/dev/sda6                 977    143       767  16% /boot
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

so I guess you could use 200 1-M blocks for `/boot` and 1800 for `/`.

Swap space should be (Size of RAM) * 1.2 (or  *2.0).